# Krusader - How to go to file?

Tags: focus, krusader

i have many files in directory and I would like to the focus to be transported to files with name staring with "ble", how to do it? in totalcmd you would hold alt and type "ble"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just start typing the filename, without holding anything down, to jump to the file. This is how it works for me, but I'm not sure whether that's the default behavior.

If it doesn't work, try going to Settings > Configure Krusader... and select the Panel tab. There should be a section under that for Quicksearch. I have "New style quicksearch" selected.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the **search** option or the **select group** option under **edit**.

Comment: yup, the default shortcut is Ctrl + +